# Google deployment manager fails when the MIG (managed instance group) and the load balancer are in the same config file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager, infrastructure-as-code

I'm working on IaC (Goole Deployment Manager - Python and YAML) and tinkering with Google's external load balancer. As part of the PoC I created:

1. An instance template based on ubuntu with startup script installing apache2 and an index.html file.
2. Create an instance group based on the above template.
3. Place an external HTTP load balancer in front of the instance group.
4. A network and a firewall rule to make debugging easier.

I heavily borrowed from [Cloud Foundation Toolkit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit), and I'm showing only the config part of the code below. I used Python for templating.

```yaml
imports:
- path: ../network/vpc/vpc_network.py
  name: vpc_network.py
- path: ../network/firewall/firewall_rule.py
  name: firewall_rule.py
- path: ../compute/instance_template/instance_template.py
  name: instance_template.py
- path: ../compute/health_checks/health_check.py
  name: health_check.py
- path: ../compute/instance_group/mananged/instance_group.py
  name: instance_group.py
- path: ../network_services/load_balancing/external_loadBalancers/external_load_balancer.py
  name: external_load_balancer.py

resources:
- name: demo-firewall-rules-1
  type: firewall_rule.py
  properties:
    rules:
    - name: "allow-ssh-for-all"
      description: "tcp firewall enable from all" 
      network: $(ref.net-10-69-16.network)
      priority: 1000
      action: "allow"
      direction: "INGRESS"
      sourceRanges: ['0.0.0.0/0']
      ipProtocol: "tcp"
      ipPorts: ["22"]
    - name: "test-health-check-for-ig"
      description: "enable health check to work on the project" 
      network: $(ref.net-10-69-16.network)
      priority: 1000
      action: "allow"
      direction: "INGRESS"
      sourceRanges: ['130.211.0.0/22', '35.191.0.0/16']
      ipProtocol: "tcp"
      ipPorts: ["80", "443"]
    - name: "allow-http-https-from-anywhere"
      description: "allow http and https from anywhere" 
      network: $(ref.net-10-69-16.network)
      priority: 1000
      action: "allow"
      direction: "INGRESS"
      sourceRanges: ['0.0.0.0/0']
      ipProtocol: "tcp"
      ipPorts: ["80", "443"]

- name: net-10-69-16
  type: vpc_network.py
  properties:
    subnetworks:
      - region: australia-southeast1
        cidr: 10.69.10.0/24
      - region: australia-southeast1
        cidr: 10.69.20.0/24
      - region: australia-southeast1
        cidr: 10.69.30.0/24

- name: mig-regional-1
  type: instance_group.py
  properties:
    region: australia-southeast1
    instanceTemplate: $(ref.it-demo-1.selfLink)
    targetSize: 2
    autoHealingPolicies:
    - healthCheck: $(ref.demo-http-healthcheck-MIG-1.selfLink)
      initialDelaySec: 400

- name: it-demo-1
  type: instance_template.py
  properties:
    machineType: n1-standard-1
    tags:
      items:
        - http
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot-disk-v1
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2004-focal-v20201211
        diskType: pd-ssd
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: $(ref.net-10-69-16.network)
      subnetwork: $(ref.net-10-69-16.subnetworks[0])
      accessConfigs:
      - type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT 
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          sudo apt-get install -y apache2
          sudo apt-get install -y php7.0
          sudo service apache2 restart
          sudo echo "Ho Ho Ho from $HOSTNAME" > /var/www/html/index.html  

- name: demo-http-healthcheck-MIG-1
  type: health_check.py
  properties:
    type: HTTP
    checkIntervalSec: 5
    timeoutSec: 5
    unhealthyThreshold: 2
    healthyThreshold: 2
    httpHealthCheck: 
      port: 80
      requestPath: /

- name: http-elb-1
  type: external_load_balancer.py
  properties:
    portRange: 80
    backendServices:
      - resourceName: backend-service-for-http-1
        sessionAffinity: NONE
        affinityCookieTtlSec: 1000
        portName: http
        healthCheck: $(ref.demo-http-healthcheck-MIG-1.selfLink)
        backends:
          - group: $(ref.mig-regional-1.selfLink)
            balancingMode: UTILIZATION
            maxUtilization: 0.8
    urlMap:
      defaultService: backend-service-for-http-1
```

The problem is with the load balancer. When it is present in the same file, the deployment fails saying the managed instance group `mig-regional-1` does not exist. But when I move the load balancer part out of this file and deploy the load balancer separately, (after a bit of delay) it all goes through well.

The most probable explanation is, the instance group is not ready when the load balancer is trying to reference it which is the exact situation `ref.*.selfLink` is supposed to handle.

This is not exactly a blocker, but it is nice to have the entire config in 1 file.

So, my questions:

1. Have any of you faced this before or am I missing something here?
2. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: can you provide the errror that is generated when you try to run this deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Your template need to explicit its dependencies.

> You can have dependencies between your resources, such as when you
> need certain parts of your environment to exist before you can deploy
> other parts of the environment.

You can specify dependencies using the `dependsOn` option in your templates.

Seems that your External LB needs `dependsOn` attribute that has MIG value.

refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-explicit-dependencies) to get more information about expliciting dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with dependsOn, I have the exact same issue.

Comment: In fact, this makes me question role of dependsOn. The part without the load balancer works just fine with just ref.

Comment: As i found, Deployment manager creates each resources in parallel even if use dependsOn.. You can workaround this to using "reference". refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-references) to get more informations.

Comment: Yes, I was and still am using reference, as mentioned above

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing right now. Looks like, there is no way of placing the LB and the MIG in the same file. I would go out on a limb and say that this is a bug with GDM!!!

Comment: when you use a reference, this does an implicit dependsOn, the order does not seem to be the issue